# Jmeter-2.3.1 - HTTPS with client certificate

Tags: https, jmeter

I am using jakarta-jmeter-2.3.1 and needs to call a SOAP webservice over HTTPS. The server needs client side certificate.

Can you please let me know how to refer keystore in earlier version of the jmeter?

I know the latest version (3.2) has Keystore Configuration sampler element, which I could not find in 2.3.1.

[I need to use that versoin because of the client side restriction. ]

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the encryption on [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) level by adding the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=${keystoretype}
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/certificate
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_certificate_password_here
```

- `${keystoretype}` can be either `pkcs12` for .p12 files or `jks` for .jks files (this is default). If your certificate is in the different format it will be better to convert it to i.e. `.p12` format using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) or equivalent
- you will need to restart JMeter to pick the properties up

See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) guide for more detailed information if needed.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

But I guess this option will change my system level JVM setting. I am not sure if I have access to this, in client environment.

Is there anything that can be done specific to jmeter, instead of changing JVM properties?

Comment: This is **JMeter** configuration file, it is located in it's "bin" folder, the properties change will have impact only on JVM session which is running JMeter. You can even pass them via -D command-line arguments like: `jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret`. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter 2.3.1 is highly outdated, more than 1000 bugs and 500 enhancements occured since that one.

Convince your customer to upgrade, you'll gain at all levels:

- productivity
- quality
- performance
- reporting